# X79 Boot issues after removing PSU

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, power-supply

This issue has me pretty stumped. So basically I'm running an older i7-3930 on an Asus x79 chipset, with a ati 7970 gpu, an intel 128gb ssd, a couple of older seagate SATA mech. drives and a kingston ssd. I can't get the thing to boot back into Windows 10. My housemate bricked his rig pretty hard so I swapped in my PSU to test whether it was the PSU.

So I've had this persistent issue with it for quite some time where I take out a piece of hardware (usually a hard drive) and the SATA controller seems to shard itself. I was prepared for that in this eventuality.

So after plugging the PSU back in, the rig eventually posted (she's a temperamental old girl). But it kicked me to a grub rescue prompt. It says "device [alpha-numeric string] cannot be found] or something a long those lines.

So I'm assuming grub has an issue with the SSD. Nothing too far removed from what I've experienced before - although I should point out that this is a Windows 10 machine, I'm assuming it's a linux partition coming to the fore.

Okay so I whack in a copy of windows 10 on USB into the rig and it takes a while to start thinking and then after the loading animation finishes, the screen just fades to black.

I'm fairly certain that there's a windows installer behind that black screen because the rig no longer shuts down automatically when I press the power button on the case (long press works though, as per standard windows behaviour).

I'm just not sure what's going on here. I'm going to try a linux USB and then see where to go from there. But anyone else got any ideas on this?

Edit: I booted it off an Ubuntu live usb. After leaving it idle for about five minutes, the screen faded again and wouldn't respond/turn back on.

So my goal here is trying to fix the rig to get windows 10 running. However, I can't seem to identify why the screen keeps dying on me. I've got two discrete GPUs in the machine and they both do it.

Before taking out the PSU the thing was fine. Now I'm trying to determine whether this is a power issue, a GPU issue or what it could be.

Edit2:

So I was able to boot it under ubuntu from a live usb with relative ease. It wants Windows to mount the drives. But running a windows install from either usb or DVD, the screen fades to black and I can't see the installer.

In order to start the startup repair from the Windows Installer - I need the screen to not fade to black. Ubuntu live usb seems to work fine and gparted knows the disks are there - so what I need to do is find a way to get that windows installer running. Hopefully that is clear enough.

Comment: The issue is that the monitor seems to power off when accessing GUIs and won't come back on - and I'm trying to identify the root cause. How do I fix this?

I thought the question was quite obvious

Comment: could you borrow a spare video card? Also, the long press will shut down the system from any situation

Comment: I have two in there already, it's affecting both of them. Yep - both short press will shut down from grub rescue and during post. So if its requiring long press it means its loaded into the windows environment.

Comment: could it be the *screen* then? liveusb and ping the system post boot?I've had a screen that did that

Comment: It did the same thing on multiple screens too. Okay so it doesn't seem to be a screen issue/gpu issue. 

In live usb its complaining that it can't mount any of the boot drives as "they are in an unsafe state". Gparted can't read one of the boot drives. But I am unsure if that's the actual windows install. So it is as I suspected a boot issue. I'm also wondering if the PSU is playing a role here.